# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AVPlayer'

Tags: xcode, swift, avplayer

I'm having an issue getting my video to play via AVPlayer.  For some reason I'm getting the error 'Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AVPlayer' with an argument list of type '(URL:NSURL)'

The weird thing is, this exact code snippet works in another one of my projects.  I do have the AVKit and AVFoundation frameworks imported.

[image: Code Image]

Comment: Why is AVPlayer highlighted in the "custom class" color? Do you have a custom definition of it somewhere?

Comment: Dont post a screen shot post your actual code

Answer (score 0):

Well, I realized my dumb mistake.  I had a local variable (player), so it died instantly before it could even play. I moved it up a level to be an instance variable so it persists as long as the view controller persists.

```
    var MoviePlaying:Bool = false
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("big_buck_bunny_720p_50mb", ofType:"mp4")
    var player: AVPlayer = AVPlayer()
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()


  @IBAction func PlayTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        let moviePlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("big_buck_bunny_720p_50mb", ofType:"mp4")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
        var player: AVPlayer = AVPlayer()
        playerVC.player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        self.presentViewController(playerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("big_buck_bunny_720p_50mb", withExtension: "mp4")!